# Infinite Loop Error while Running Chatroom in Terminal using Python

Tags: python, sockets

I have implemented a simple chatroom using python. When the users exits (closes the terminal window) the program breaks and show an endless loop of a message. I have the following code to treat exception (when no message is received) but, it doesn't go into that and doesn't close the client socket connection. Any help would be highly appreciated on how shall I close the client socket after it disconnects? Thanks!

```
def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            messages = message.decode('ascii')
            index = clients.index(client)
            clientname = clientnames[index]
            print("<{}> {}".format(clientname, messages))
            broadcast("({}) {}".format(clientname, messages).encode('ascii'), index)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clientname = clientnames[index]
            print("{} left!".format(clientname))
            broadcast('{} left!'.format(clientname).encode('ascii'), index)
            clientnames.remove(clientname)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            break
```

Comment: You don't need an exception for when no message is received as `client.recv(1024)` is a blocking call (if youre using `socket`) that waits until something is received

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Right i see! So I just use if (messages == "") then client.close() ?

Comment: no, because no code after `client.recv()` will be executed if there is no message. you can add something like `if (message == "close bot"): client.close()` or if you want the keyboard interrupt, catch the interrupt

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Thanks! Could you please give it as an answer by editing my code below? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According my comments, giving you this piece of code. I don't if its working right away, because I have not seen the other methods you implemented yet. Especially, check if `messages` is a list or something as the name implies and change accordingly.

Function: If you send `quit` to the bot, everything will be closed

```
def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            messages = message.decode('ascii')
            if messages == "quit":
                print("{} left!".format(clientname))
                broadcast('{} left!'.format(clientname).encode('ascii'), index)
                clientnames.remove(clientname)
                clients.remove(client)
                client.close()
                break
            index = clients.index(client)
            clientname = clientnames[index]
            print("<{}> {}".format(clientname, messages))
            broadcast("({}) {}".format(clientname, messages).encode('ascii'), index)
        except:
            print("Error on receiving")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!